# Andorid studio- making different layouts using sw qualifier

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making an app, and i'm having a problem to make it responsive using the sw qualifier. Most of the cellular devices go into the sw320dp, and my problem is that in one group of devices in this category (sw320dp), my layouts are presented great, but in the other group of devices in this category, everything is looking terrible, because they have small screens. So i can't change them with this sw qualifier.
I know that there are size qualifiers (Different layouts for medium screen size, large or xlarge), but iv'e been told that they are not in use anymore. 
How can i resolve that? Thanks a lot!

My layout.xml: It contains few buttons with footaball leagues names on each one. Pressing on one button will show the user the desired league table.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shaytsabar
    .footballtables.fragments.ChooseLeagueFragm
    ent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ligue1_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flagfrance"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ligue1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/bundesliga_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bundesliga_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ligue2_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flagfrance"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ligue2"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ligue1_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/bundesliga2_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eredvise_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flagnetherlands"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/eredvise"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/ligue1_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ligue1_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seriaa_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flagitaly"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/seria_A"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/eredvise_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eredvise_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seriab_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flagitaly"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/seria_B"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/seriaa_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/spanish_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/spanish_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flagspain"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/spanishleague"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/eredvise_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/ligue2_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/brazil_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flagbrazil"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/brazilleague"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/portugese_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/seriab_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/portugese_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flagportugal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/portugeseleague"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/seriaa_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seriaa_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bundesliga_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-42dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flaggermany"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/bundesliga"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/premierleague_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/premierleague_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bundesliga2_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flaggermany"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/secbundesliga"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bundesliga_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/championship_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/championship_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flagengland"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/shrtchampionship"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/premierleague_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/premierleague_btn"
            android:layout_width="149dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="#9bdbc7"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/flagengland"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/premier_league"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#191917"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your layout xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a few groups: sw320dp, sw360dp, sw400dp

- sw320dp in this case will serve 320-360 smallest width screens
- sw360dp will 360-400
- sw400dp will 400+

your default layout file will handle all screens upto 320 in this setup.